# OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'JOE-PC\SQLAnalysis'

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I am learning how to create Data Warehouse. I am following to [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/658912/Create-First-OLAP-Cube-in-SQL-Server-Analysis-Serv?msg=4704606#xx4704606xx). I have created database in SQL Server. In BIDS, I have added that database as datasource. Then added data source view. Then cube with its dimensions. Created hierarchy as shown in tutorial. In step 9, while processing project, BIDS giving error:

> SalesDataAnalize
>         
>         ProcessFull
>         UseExisting
>       
>     
>   
>       Processing Database 'SalesDataAnalize' completed.
>           Start time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; End time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
>           Processing Dimension 'Dim Date' completed.
>               Start time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; End time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
>               Processing Dimension Attribute '(All)' completed.
>                   Start time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; End time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
>               Processing Dimension Attribute 'Month' completed.
>                   Start time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; End time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
>               Processing Dimension Attribute 'Quarter' completed.
>                   Start time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; End time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
>               Processing Dimension Attribute 'Year' completed.
>                   Start time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; End time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
>           Processing Dimension 'Dim Product' completed.
>               Start time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; End time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
>               Processing Dimension Attribute '(All)' completed.
>                   Start time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; End time: 11/19/2013 1:59:45 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
>   Errors and Warnings from Response
>       Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
>       OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'JOE-PC\SQLAnalysis'.; 28000.
>       Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Sales DW', Name of 'Sales DW'.
>       Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Date', Name of 'Dim Date' was being processed.
>       Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Year' attribute of the 'Dim Date' dimension from the 'SalesDataAnalize' database was being processed.
>       Server: The operation has been cancelled.
>       OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'JOE-PC\SQLAnalysis'.; 28000.
>       Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Sales DW', Name of 'Sales DW'.
>       Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Date', Name of 'Dim Date' was being processed.
>       Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Month' attribute of the 'Dim Date' dimension from the 'SalesDataAnalize' database was being processed.
>       OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'JOE-PC\SQLAnalysis'.; 28000.
>       Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Sales DW', Name of 'Sales DW'.
>       Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Date', Name of 'Dim Date' was being processed.
>       Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Quarter' attribute of the 'Dim Date' dimension from the 'SalesDataAnalize' database was being processed.

What can cause to this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account that you're using does not have process permissions to the cube or dimension. Here's a link that covers the security model.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175426.aspx

Once you grant the necessary permissions, you should be able to process the cube.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error while following the below process for creating SalesDataAnalytical cube from 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/658912/Create-First-OLAP-Cube-in-SQL-Server-Analysis-Serv

Please change the datasource connection string properties
Steps

1.Double Click on Sales DW.ds under Data Sources Folder.
2.In General Tab Hit on Edit Button.
3.Now Provide Your Server and choose your authentication Type to connect to SQL server.
4.Choose Sales_DW database and test connection

Now your Process will work

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am not running ssms with Administrator privileges. I have closed ssms adn run as administrator solved my problem.